# Looking for a formula to find each pair of previous sums in an incremental series that will equal the next sum in the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation

I imagine this should be easy for a lot of you, or maybe is a well known thing.

So, I am looking to find previously found value pairs that can sum to the next value in a sequence that increments by one.

Example:

base value = 1
2:  (1+1)
3:  (1+2)
4:  (1+3, 2+2)
5:  (1+4, 2+3)
6:  (3+3, 2+4, 5+1)
7:  (3+4, 2+5, 6+1)

so... it looks like it is each pair i,j where i = 1 up to floor(k/2)+1 and j = k-i

did I get this correct?  thanks for help

Comment: This really looks like the sequence of natural numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly: You want to know how many ways you can find two natural numbers that sum to a given natural number, $n$.

Then, in your notation, the possibilities are:

$$(1, n-1), (2, n-2), (3, n-3), \ldots, (n-3, 3), (n-2, 2), (n-1, 1)$$

But, it looks like you don't want to count $(a, b)$ and $(b, a)$ as distinct.

So, you can have the first entry go from $1$ to the halfway point, which (as in your post) is either $n/2$ if $n$ is even **or** $(n-1)/2$ if $n$ is odd.

Indeed, this can be rewritten as $\text{floor}(n/2)$ in total, just as you observed.